# "Type or namespace name could not be found" in UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, controls

I want to do the following in a UserControl:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is CheckBox)
   {
       // Do stuff here
   }
}
```

But I get the the error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Control' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Error 2   The type or namespace name 'CheckBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thankyou for the guidance.

Comment: Did you import `System.Windows.Forms.Control`?

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you exactly what the problem is. You need to import the 2 DLLs that correspond to `Control` and `Checkbox`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to include either `System.Web.UI.WebControls` or `System.Windows.Forms` (depending on the type of the app you are developing) with `using` directive.

Comment: @PM yes sure i will after 7 mins wait time

Answer (score 3):

You should add either System.Windows.Forms, or System.Web.UI.WebControls, or System.Windows.Controls depending on what technology you use

Answer (score 2):

You need to add   [`System.Windows.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx) namespace which includes *System.Windows.Forms.dll* for [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) class.

Also you need to add [`System.Web.UI.WebControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.aspx) namespace which includes *System.Web.dll* for [`Checkbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.aspx) class.

Like;

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add System.Windows.Forms.dll.

It's located in `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.